# Intervalos de Tiempo con Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola amigos tengo una inconveniente que he estado luchando en las ultimas horas, resulta que tengo que gráficar las conversaciones que no han sido respondidas, y estas las catalogo desde mysql, de forma:

un día, 3 días, 1 semana, y un mes, pongo el ejemplo que tengo 417 conversaciones de un mes que no hay sido contestadas
ahora mostraré las sentencias sql que utilizo para sacar los intervalos;

1. Esta es la primera sql que me trae los inbox que son de 1 día todo genial, esta me devuelve como cantidad 30 conversaciones que no se han contestado en el día

---

```
SELECT count(conver.ID_CONVERSACION) as inbox_un_dia  from mensaje as msj 
INNER JOIN conversacion as conver on msj.conversacion_id_conversacion =  conver.ID_CONVERSACION where msj.created_time = conver.UPDATED_TIME 
and msj.id_from <> $id_pagina and conver.pagina_ID_PAGINA = $id_pagina and msj.created_time between DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '1' DAY) and NOW() ORDER BY conver.ID_CONVERSACION
```

2. esta consulta trae los mensajes de 3 dias y me da como resultado 48.

---

```
SELECT count(conver.ID_CONVERSACION) as inbox_tres_dias  from mensaje 
                    as msj INNER JOIN conversacion as conver 
                    on msj.conversacion_id_conversacion =  conver.ID_CONVERSACION where msj.created_time =  conver.UPDATED_TIME 
                    and msj.id_from <> $id_pagina and conver.pagina_ID_PAGINA = $id_pagina and msj.created_time between
                       DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '3' DAY) and NOW() ORDER BY conver.ID_CONVERSACION
```

3. En este caso es la semana y me da como resultado 88 utilizando una consulta similar

---

```
SELECT count(conver.ID_CONVERSACION) as inbox_una_semana  from mensaje 
                    as msj INNER JOIN conversacion as conver 
                    on msj.conversacion_id_conversacion =  conver.ID_CONVERSACION where msj.created_time =  conver.UPDATED_TIME 
                    and msj.id_from <> $id_pagina and conver.pagina_ID_PAGINA = $id_pagina and msj.created_time between
                         DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '1' WEEK) and NOW() ORDER BY conver.ID_CONVERSACION
```

ok amigos ahora mi problema es este, cuando se crean las conversaciones de un día, esta todo genial, pero cuando tengo por ejemplo 3 días me muestra 48 los cuales en realidad solo pertenecen 18 mensajes porque me toma el 1er día, y lo que necesito es como mandar el parámetro al between, de antemano les agradecería mucho, ya que soy nuevo en esto  :$

Comment: si la consulta la estás haciendo por php, has tratado en pasar el between mediante php en lugar de directo de la bd?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Entre tanto código y explicaciones, al final no explicaste el problema de manera clara. Por favor, edita la pregunta y explica cuál es el problema en sí en el primer párrafo. Así quizá entendamos todo el contexto luego leyendo el resto de la pregunta.

Comment: Necesitas que el resultado de los 3 dias en realidad sea `resultado 3 dias` - `resultado dia1`?